# How can I run Ubuntu on VirtualBox in full screen on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox, ubuntu-11.04, fullscreen

I use Windows 7 and use VirtualBox to run Ubuntu Desktop 11.04. I would like to run Ubuntu in full screen. But when I switch to full screen in VirtualBox, a lot of space around Ubuntu isn't used. Is there any way I can do so Ubuntu uses all my screen space when I have VirtualBox in full screen mode?

I have tried with installing the Guest Additions (by autorun).

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? There are lots of guides out there already, all based around installing the Guest Additions.

Comment: @Ruairi: I use 11.04 and I think I have installed the Guest Addition with "autorun".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the Guest Additions installed, this should fix the problem...

Before you start you machine, go to settings -> display and set you video memory high (e.g. 128MB)

Start you machine then select full screen, should be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

If it still doesn't work, just resize the VirtualBox window and suddenly Ubuntu will occupy the full screen if you maximize the window again.